# Shadow to a transparent UITableView and rounded corners

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, transparency

I need to give my table rounded corners and a drop shadow outside its borders. The table does not take the whole screen so I can't just turn off maskToBounds and clipsToBounds to NO, as the cells will be leaking off the bottom edge of the table.

I tried setting up values for the layer shadow like this:

```
[layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(-2.0, 2.0)];
[layer setShadowRadius:6.0];
[layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[layer setCornerRadius:6.0];
[layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
```

and though the table draws a shadow, it does so on the inside of the table. And not only that, but it does it to each of the dividing lines of the cells too.

I tried adding a UIView and putting my UITableView inside that view, and making that view transparent as well as the table. I did the same settings on the UIView's layer and it behaves exactly the same, aka the dividing lines for each cell get a shadow and the table draws its shadow on the inside.

I have found similar solutions and work but for tables that cover the whole screen or for tables that have opaque cells but not for a transparent table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to round the table's corners and at the same time add shadow to it, what I ended up doing that worked was:

1. Add a UIView that contains your table
2. Add your table to that UIView
3. Round and add shade to the UIView's layer
4. Round (but don't add shadow) to your table's layer

tah-dah!